# How to compare time with moment js?

Tags: node.js, momentjs, dialogflow-es, chatbot

When I put until 9h, the code works, but when I input 10h, 11h, or 12h, the code doesn't work. The Dialogflow recognizes like 22h or 23h or 00h. What I'm doing wrong? Any suggestions for my programming?
P.S: I would like to work with the 24h format.

```
  function consulta(agent) {
    moment.locale("pt-BR");
    const agora = moment();
    
    let tempo = agent.parameters.time;
    let data = agent.parameters.date;
    
    let dataFormatada = moment(data).format('l');
    let week = moment(data).weekday();
    
    var a = moment(agent.parameters.time).tz("America/Recife");
    let horaFormatada = moment(a).get('hour');
    //let tempoFormatado = (moment(a).format('hh:mm'));
    let tempoFormatado = (moment(a).format('LT'));
    let horaAbrir = moment('08:00', 'LT');
    let checkAbrir = moment(horaAbrir).get('hour');
    
    let horaFechar = moment('17:00', 'LT');
    let checkFechar = moment(horaFechar).get('hour');
    
    
    if (horaFormatada < checkAbrir){
      agent.add(`Marque após às 8h`);
    } else if (horaFormatada > checkFechar){
      agent.add(`Marque antes das 17h`);
    } else if (week === 0 || week === 6){
      agent.add(`Não abrimos nos finais de semana.`);
    } else {
      agent.add(`Ok, pode marcar`);
    }
    
  }
```

Comment: I guess I don't totally get the exact point of what you're saying the problem is for it not working for 10-12, but to get it to format moment into the 24 hour format use `HH` instead of `hh`. There's more documentation here https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Comment: The code is working very well to me, the only problem is when a user input 12h the code recognizes 22h instead 12:00. The same problem with 11h and 10h.